# c# Windows Forms, how can I use a variable from a form in another class?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, constructor

So I had this app made that worked in a console. It is very simple, I create a catalog in main class, and then engage it. From then on, all the actions happens in a class called "catalog", it reads the console from there, so all the variables are local in that class.

Now I was forced to recreate that app in Windows Forms. After a couple of hours learning how to use it, I faced a major problem. While I by now know how to read the variables I need, I noticed I cannot use them in a different class.

So far I have read a string, and an array of integers (I used ArrayList) in a form. Now I need to access those two variables (string name and ArrayList numbersUsed) in my catalog class, but it says they "do not exist in current context".

How can I use the variables read from forms in other classes? I am a complete beginner with C#, so sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: pass it in its constructor

Comment: Create a constructor for your new class that is passed the two variables as parameters.  Or make the variables `public`, and instead pass a reference to your form object that contains these variables.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize new form like this and pass data to it in constructor.

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
string str ="";
Form2 form2 = new Form2(str, arr);
```

Constructor:

```
public Form2(string strvar, ArrayList arrList)
        {
            //Use strvar and arrList 
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```